# SSAS query log table is always empty

Tags: ssas

I am trying to build a report to display the usage of cube such as executed query,user name, start time of the query ,duration of the query and some other information. This report will be helpful for optimization of performance .

I followed the process mentioned in this link,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917676.aspx

Table 'OLAPQueryLog' was successfully created but no rows are getting added in it . Technically rows should get populated as the cube is accessed by any user.(When a query is executed on the cube) .

I would really appreciate any immediate help .Please reach out to me if you have any concerns.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks P.J.Meisch..

Comment: Is this SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular?

Comment: It is a tabular model !

Comment: @PasupathyDevaraj OLAPQueryLog does not work for SSAS Tabular mode.

Comment: @Gabe. where did you get this from?

Comment: @Gabe, found it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/server-properties/log-properties?view=sql-analysis-services-2022

Query Log
Applies to: Multidimensional server mode only

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is that SSAS does not have permissions to write to the log table. Make sure that the account that SSAS service is running under, has Insert permissions to the SQL database that hosts the QueryLog table. You can check the Event Viewer on the machine that runs SSAS to see the error message SSAS is producing.